# javascript error array creation

Tags: javascript, arrays, creation

this is the code

```
var xyzTris = [[[0,-3,4],[-2,0,4],[2,0,4]]];
console.log("zero: ",rdfTris);
var scrTris = [[[]]];
console.log("first: ",scrTris);
var rdfTris = [[[]]];
console.log("second: ",rdfTris);
```

What's strange is, the console out shows:

```
zero: undefined
first: Array [[[]]]
second: Array [[[0, -3, 4]]]
```

Anybody get why the rdfTris array is mal-defined?

I've tried all sorts of rearrangements, the parser just seems confused by rdfTris and xyzTris.  I discovered this downstream when I was getting some weird array elements not defined later in the code.  Stripped all that away to get to this.

Comment: Because you're logging `rdfTris` before assigning a value to it. Note, that only declarations are hoisted, not assignments.

Comment: where are you trying this .. just tried on chrome console the second array is coming fine ,

Comment: Are the three letters before `Tris` meaningful, (`xyz`, `scr`, `rdf`)?  Consider using longer more descriptive names to prevent confusions like this

Comment: To avoid this type of mistakes, you'd better use the `let` keyword, instead of `var`.

Comment: Thanks for input; the prefixes are incidental - xyz versus right-down-forward versus screen coordinates.  I didn't want to edit anything lest I "fix" or change things somehow.  I didn't use let over var because these are acting as global arrays.  I got tired of passing references to every other function.  Also, I realize the undefined is expected - what I am focused on is that once the rdf array IS defined, it takes on the value of the xyz array.  Meanwhile, the scr array is initialized fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are logging the value of `rdfTris` on line 2, but you assign a value to `rdfTris` on line 5.

```
var xyzTris = [[[0,-3,4],[-2,0,4],[2,0,4]]];
console.log("zero: ",xyzTris);
var scrTris = [[[]]];
console.log("first: ",scrTris);
var rdfTris = [[[]]];
console.log("second: ",rdfTris);
```

The above should work as expected.

Comment: Hoisting is a strange thing, for example; you don't get `rdfTris is not defined` error even though you are using it before it is defined (suggests hoisting) but then it doesn't have a value even though you assign it a value when you define/declare it. This is because as Teemu suggested that declarations are hoisted but not assignments. Better answer would be to avoid `var` and stick to `let` if you plan to re assign and `const` if not.

Comment: @HMR Totally agree, I think 'strange' is probably an understatement! I made the assumption that the poster was in an environment where `const` and `let` were unavailable. If they *are*, then definitely. I also think the suggestion by @IrkenInvader to use meaningful variable names would have helped!

Comment: JSLint used to complain if you did not declare all your variables at the start of the function so in an old environment I would suggest using that since the linter would point out that code as a possible mistake.